# Latch of cup holder in main console broken

Tags: interior

The latch in my car console is broken. When I have checked the dealer they tell me I have to change the whole console. That costs around $300. I am looking to fix it using some glue. Has anyone tried to glue some plastic parts before? Which type of glue will be better for latch?

Answer (score 2):

Regular super glue works well for abs plastic.  If that doesn't work, epoxy also works well.